# Pivot Table distinct count of employees

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In Excel I have raw data that looks like this:
[image]

I am creating a pivot table that lists employees and the days they punched in by department / shift.
[image]

I'd like the Employee Count to give a count of the distinct number of employees in the particular Department / Shift.  Currently the pivot table is showing a count of the total number of rows in which each employee appears.
Instead of **1st SHIFT Warehouse 44th** having a total of 69 I want it to have a total of 5.  And no values alongside the individual employee rows.  When I change Count to Sum I get values of 0.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the pivot table, check the box for "Add this data to the data model". Then design your pivot table, doing on a count on employee. Lastly, right click on the employee count in your pivot, go to Value Field Settings, and change your Summarize to Distinct Count.

Comment: That works thanks, I see when I minimize the department I get a distinct employee count.  But when I expand each department to display employee names each employee has a 1 at the end of their row in the Employee Count column.  I would like only the total number of employees on the department row and if I drill down further, nothing is to be displayed.  Is this the right approach?

Comment: That is correct. Each row will have a value such as 1. So you should notice that your example went from David Hatcher 12 to David Hatcher 1. You'll see a 1 by his name regardless of how you drill into this. If you're not seeing a value, then you need to share more data on how you are setting up the table.